# Jackson's ObjectMapper, serialize list

Tags: java, list, jackson

I wrote simple wrapper around Jackson's `ObjectMapper` which would convert `List<?>` to `String`:

```
public static <T> String listToString(List<T> list) {
    if (list == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, if I pass empty `ArrayList` there, `mapper.writeValueAsString(list)` is executed around 2 seconds. I'm testing in debug in eclipse.
Why is it executed for so much time? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A Jackson `ObjectMapper` is relatively expensive to create, but once created it can be re-used for many conversions very cheaply.  Your benchmark is flawed as it includes the `ObjectMapper` creation time in the measurement.  A better benchmark would create *one* `ObjectMapper` up front, then perform several hundred or thousand conversions using the same mapper and calculate the *average* time per conversion.  If you do this you'll see much more respectable numbers.

An `ObjectMapper` instance is thread-safe once fully configured, so it would be safe to do the following (exception handling code ignored for clarity)

```
public class X {
  private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  public static <T> String listToString(List<T> list) {
    if(list == null) return null;
    else return MAPPER.writeValueAsString(list);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to rewrite code in such a way, but that didn't help. It turned out later, the problem was in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was in debugger. If I do this in debug mode, it takes code 2-5 seconds to be executed. But if I do the same thing without debugger and log execution time, it is executed within 0,1-0,8 milliseconds - fast enough.